# Asynchronous programming in C# async and await

Tags: c#, asynchronous

What is the difference between asyn and thread?
Does it internally uses thread?

Comment: After some research (and article reading), what questions remain?

Comment: Async methods can be implemented via threads, but is not restricted to threads. Especially for I/O operation you want to avoid threads to achieve asynchronicity, but instead async methods here use different often notification-based mechanisms.

Comment: This question is hard to answer because first, as noted, there's no indication that you've done any research, and second, because "what's the difference" questions are hard to answer. Tell you what, if you tell me "what is the difference between a chef and a recipe?" then that will help me understand what difference you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread` an actual thread potentially started and ran on code from your application.

`async` is just a C# keyword (`Async` in VB.NET) that tells the compiler that the method can become a continuation.  This usually happens with the `await` keyword as long as a proper `TaskAwaiter` is found.

`async await` is NOT the same as a `Thread` but using the two often have similar logic.

With a `Thread` you can reference and invoke it to perform any delegated work.  The thread will run until the delegated work has completed or it throws an error.

NOTE: Referencing a `new Thread` is different than pulling one from the application thread pool.  When you reference a `new Thread`, by default, you're allowing it to keep your process alive even if you end the application (so manage them well.)  Ideally, most application threads should be pulled from the application thread pool.  Thread pool threads perform better simply because they are usually already allocated and reusable; they will also end when the main thread ends (application thread), allowing the process to end.

Examples of `new Thread` vs `ThreadPool`

```
//Runs from application thread pool... Ends with process.
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) => { /* do some work */ });

//Allocates a new thread; by default runs until completed reaching UnhandledException keeping the process alive.
new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {  /* do some work */ })).Start();
```

Now, we could do this with a `Task` also like so:

```
//Runs from application thread pool... Ends with process.
new Task(() => {  /* do some work */ }).Start();
```

You'll notice that `Task` is similar to `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` in this example and in fact they are very much alike with what they are doing.  However; not to confuse you too much just note that `Task` does NOT have to be thread.  In this example it is.

Comment: _"When you reference a `new Thread` you're allowing it to continue running even if your application ends"_ - This part might be a bit misleading. If the process your application runs in is terminated then any threads belonging to it will be terminated as well. A raw thread cannot continue to run _without_ your application's process.

Comment: However it is true that threads which have [`IsBackground = false`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/foreground-and-background-threads) (known as _foreground threads_) will continue to run even after your UI/other threads are closed, because it is considered to be an active part of the application. But in that case your process is still alive and thus the application is not _actually_ closed.

Comment: @VisualVincent I've edited the code and introduced the word process; hopefully to clarify the difference between application and process as well as add "by default" when declaring a ```new thread```; where you can say ```IsBackground= true``` to change this behavior.